# How to use options in rundeck through python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, rundeck

I am trying to run python requests in rundeck , it is working for me in the case of hardcoded key value in URL for GET method. but I wanted to use rundeck options so that I can pass key values during run time . please let me know the steps for this in python .
this is working fine for me in bash .I have used below code in script after creating options in rundeck.

Bash scripts 
A=@option.Adata@
curl --location -k --request GET "URL?Adata=$A&selector=A,B,C" \

Thanks in advance .

RK

Comment: Never mind , this is working for me now . I have changed the job definition in advanced section (by using the python interpreter path at Invocation String textbox and ".py" at "File Extension" textbox). python -u scriptfile.py

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options in the same way of Bash inline-scripts, just make sure that you're using the python interpreter path at Invocation String textbox and ".py" at "File Extension" textbox (both accessible if you click on "Advanced" button at the moment of creating or editing your job).

I leave an example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='name' value='a devops guy' />
        <option name='years' value='12' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>cc910bb3-9672-4038-b1e1-db4ec6d32e59</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobPython</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.py</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[title = "@option.name@"
years = @option.years@
print("I have been {} for {} years ".format(title, years))]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/usr/bin/python3.8</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>cc910bb3-9672-4038-b1e1-db4ec6d32e59</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Also, you can use options on your Python arguments, just make sure that you're passing those arguments on "Arguments" textbox, another example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt1' value='hello' />
        <option name='opt2' value='world' />
        <option name='opt3' value='devops' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>94045c34-0d8b-4bef-9248-08cf6f7b3a06</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobPythonWithArguments</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.py</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[import sys
print (sys.argv[1:]);]]></script>
        <scriptargs>${option.opt1} ${option.opt2} ${option.opt3}</scriptargs>
        <scriptinterpreter>/usr/bin/python3.8</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>94045c34-0d8b-4bef-9248-08cf6f7b3a06</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully execute the Job using the Python requests module with post verbs, My rundeck supports the latest api version 41, I have made the post with option in two formats,

1. XML
2. Json

**XML**

With the rundeck api reference doc optional parameters for job will be changed on API v14 and 18 or later. Below code will execute the job and get the response in xml format.

Code snip,

```
import requests, json, urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

# Variables

run_url = "https://<rundeckserver>/api/41/job/<JOB_UUID>/run"

token = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token’:”xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”}

User = “Username”
passkey = “Password”
MyOptions1 = “Value”
MyOptions2 = “Value”

options = {
    'option.UserName' : User,
    'option.winrmPassword' : passkey,
    'option.MyOptions1' : ServerName,
    'option.MyOptions2' : RetentionPeriod
}

res = requests.post(url=run_url, verify=False,headers=token, params=options )

res.content
```

**Json**

Job will triggered and out put will be in Json format

code snip,

```
import requests, json, urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

# Variables

run_url = "https://<rundeckserver>/api/41/job/<JOB UUID>/run"
token = {'Content-Type': 'application/json’, 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token’:”xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”}

User = “Username”
passkey = “Password”
MyOptions1 = “Value”
MyOptions2 = “Value”

options = {
    'option.UserName' : User,
    'option.winrmPassword' : passkey,
    'option.MyOptions1' : ServerName,
    'option.MyOptions2' : RetentionPeriod
}

opt = {'options': options}

res = requests.post(url=run_url, verify=False,headers=token, json=opt, params= {"format": "json"})

res.content
```

API Ref : https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#running-a-job